# hector_mapping reducing cpu consumption?

Tags: navigation, cpu, pandaboard, archlinux, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
I'm using hector_mapping on pandaboard es with arch linux+hydro installed. I have hokuyo urg 04lx. However when i start mapping with default settings.
rosrun urg_node urg_node
roslaunch hector_mapping mapping_default.launch
(Static transform from base_footprint to laser)
Nothing else
However, when i type "top" to see its cpu usage. It shows nothing below %105.. how can i reduce this. It this normal? Am i doing something wrong?
Is it better option for me to use laser_scan_matcher + gmapping

Edit:
I installed ros-base from Aur repository using yaourt.
After that i cloned hector_slam from from github to my catkin directory and catkin_make only hector_mapping (i installed every dependencies of it)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151466/hector_mapping-reducing-cpu-consumption?/) by [lvntbkdmr](https://answers.ros.org/users/9991/lvntbkdmr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To complete @StefanKohlbrecher's answer, the problem is that you built a part of the packages without the proper release flags. Basically, when you use the AUR's PKGBUILDs, the release flag is forwarded to CMake, but if you compile from source with `catkin_make`, you need to take care of this yourself.

That being said, I just added `hector_mapping` and its dependencies to the AUR. Remove whatever you installed with `catkin_make`, install `ros-hydro-hector-mapping` with `yaourt`, and you should be just fine. If you encounter any other missing packages in the AUR, please send a package request [here](https://github.com/bchretien/arch-ros-stacks), or even better: make a fork, generate the PKGBUILDs yourself, and send me a pull request. Note that generating, compiling, installing and sending to the AUR the missing PKGBUILDs took me less than 5 minutes, so this is definitely worth installing things this way, rather than relying on `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [bchr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4609/bchr/) with karma: 596 on 2014-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven´t tried things on Pandaboard, so not sure what to expect. That being said, I also noticed that CPU consumption lately was much higher than normal (nearly maxing out a i7 core on our USAR vehicles). As there haven´t been changes to the code in quite some time, I suspect that there might be a problem with one of the used libraries or the build settings. Can you edit your question with information on how you generated the executables (installed from .debs or compiled yourself)?

/edit: There seems to be something wrong with compile flags, see [hector_slam issue 11](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/hector_slam/issues/11)

/edit2: I´d recommend building explicitly in Release mode as suggested in above ticket, just to make sure.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think it is normal. I run hector_mapping on an Intel PC and I used to see hector_mapping over 100% all the time.

You can adjust the parameters (for me, they're in hector_mapping/mapping_default.launch) to ignore as much of the laser scan as possible. Bump up  `laser_min_distance`. Bump down `map_pub_period` and `laser_max_distance`. Maybe there are a few other parameters that have some effect. You can see a list of params on the wiki page. In hector_nav.launch, decrease the map size.

A hacky fix: you can install cpulimit and throttle the CPU usage to whatever you please. I'm using 80% without any noticeable ill effects:

```
cpulimit -e hector_mapping -l 80
```

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2017-10-12**:
This should only happen when you run things on a very weak CPU, otherwise it is very likely that you're compiling with no optimization.

**Comment by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) on 2017-10-12**:
Thanks. With the parameter changes, CPU load has dropped from ~100% to 30%. Add to CMakeLists instead of typing `catkin_make -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`:

add_executable(hector_mapping ...)

add_dep...

target_link_lib...

set_target_properties(hector_mapping PROPERTIES DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Release")